# Google Sheets addon script cannot display both homepage addon card and addon menu

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, add-on, google-workspace-add-ons

I have created a Google Sheets addon. I have used `createAddonMenu` in the `onOpen` function to create a set of addon menus. I have also configured `appscript.json` to set a `homepageTrigger` that displays an addon card.

When operating in a test environment, the `homepageTrigger` works properly and the add-on card is displayed. The add-on menus are not displayed.

When deployed to the marketplace, the opposite occurs - the addon card is never displayed, but the addon menus are displayed correctly.

I was expecting both the addon menus to display and the homepage card to display.

I should add that I am using the new runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to use the [Class Ui](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html) and [CardService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card-service) in a single add-on. Also it's not possible to use triggers like `onOpen` with triggers like `homepageTrigger`.

---

Google Apps Script could be used to create two types of add-ons, each type works in different *contexts*:

- **Workspace add-ons**. These add-ons works with CardService and triggers like `hompageTrigger` but not with Class Ui and triggers like `onOpen`. These add-ons also could be created using other runtimes.
- **Editor add-ons**. These add-ons works works with Class Ui and triggers like onOpen but not with CardService and triggers like `homepageTrigger`. These add-ons can only be created using Google Apps Script.

**Reference**

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/types
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/workspace-triggers
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

Comment: Thank you VERY much!! I searched for several days, but did not find that document that described the difference between workspace and editor add-ons. Once I understood that, the problem was solved in a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks for you reply @LJD. Please consider to post the solution that you aplied as an answer or if you find that this answer provided you what you was looking for, accept it. Ref. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: The solution was as simple as configuring the Google Marketplace to set the app as a Workspace Add-on. It was confusing because it seems to default to being a Workspace Add-on when in development. I also removed the onInstall and onOpen triggers since they are not required.

Comment: Setting the app as a Workspace Add-on did the trick for me! Thank you so much for this comment. It was driving me crazy. The description of the setting was a little misleading since it didn't include Docs, Sheet, or Presentation. Didn't think it was necessary since I was making an add-on for Docs only.